# ggplot bar plot suggestions

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Any suggestions on how to make a barplot for this data?

```
data <- data.frame(
  x=c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),  
  y=c(0.1311971,-0.07654406,0.3615017,0.5084337,0.8668116,0.4528717,-0.1093398,-0.7381238)
  )
```

specifically I am looking to make a barplot that would show the x at each interval, 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 and their corresponding data points. is this possible?

I tried

```
ggplot(data, mapping = aes(x=y, y=x)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

but it's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

could you use something `row` to make the each row distinct, the multiple zeros make it as one record, so something like `row` can help

```r
data <- data %>% mutate(row=row_number())

ggplot(data, mapping = aes(x=y, y=row)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

[image]

Comment: Hi there thank you for your help, yes that is exactly what I'm struggling with each zeros make it as one record so I am looking to have each zero be it's own record in the x axis and the y axis would be an interval from -1 to 1 not sure if this is possible

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check if this the expected output

```r
data <- data %>% mutate(x=ifelse(x==0,round(y,1),x))

ggplot(data, mapping = aes(x=y, y=x)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]